# Hiding output members with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net, rest, servicestack

I'm evaluating ServiceStack as a possible REST service we want to use in our system environment and so far i am quite happy with it.
a requirement to the service is hiding fields for particular users or user groups. depending on the key/session a user has 
not all fields of a data model are returned to the client and they have to be hidden by service stack. therefore after receiving the data object (list)
from Linq2SQL i analyse the object with reflection, extract the object members, ignore the members that are supposed to be hidden and add the other 
members to a dictionary. afterwards i pass the dictionary to ServiceStack which serializes it and sends the data structure to the client.

my questions to this setup are :

- is this the proper way to do it with ServiceStack or am I abusing a
  loophole which will be fixed soon?
- is there a ServiceStack way to achieve the same?
- are there any best practices you can recommend?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support request for an external service and should be directed at that service.

Comment: I don't think question is off-topic.

Comment: I am interesting also about this question. I suppose, that if we talk abut JavaScript clients / jQuery Ajax , then it could be possible, using a function to exclude from JSON, specific fields, according to user rights. I don't know if there is such functionality. For typed C# clients,  it is not possible, only the service code to leave empty the specific fields in the response object. But the user will now, that  such fields exist.

Comment: I haven't used it, although I probably will in the future, but you might want to look at https://github.com/AnthonyCarl/ServiceStack.PartialResponse either to use directly or for inspiration.

Comment: @Ben, ServiceStack isn't a service, it's an open source framework.

Comment: No one can know if a "loophole" might be closed save the developers and best practices are normally opinion based or massively broad @marfarma. If you want to answer all three questions and prove me wrong I'd be happy.

Comment: Just to make you happy, @Ben, I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do it with ServiceStack is to define DTOs for the purpose of your API rather than trying to use existing business objects.  If your clients are prepared to parse lists returning a DTO with a dictionary property could work.

One 'ServiceStack' way to do it would be to define a simple, flat, DTO with all possible properties, where each property is Nullable.

Given DTO defined as follows:

```
public class NullablePartials
{
    public Int32? Test1 { get; set; }
    public String Test2 { get; set; }
    public Double? Test3 { get; set; }
}
```

The following fragment:

```
Dictionary<String, String> MyDtoDictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
MyDtoDictionary.Add("Test1", "7");
MyDtoDictionary.Add("Test2", "Value2");
NullablePartials result = MyDtoDictionary.ToJson().FromJson<NullablePartials>();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(MyDtoDictionary.ToJson());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
```

produces:

```
{"Test1":"7","Test2":"Value2"}
{"Test1":7,"Test2":"Value2"}
```

using ServiceStack.Text as your JSON library in its default setting for serializing nulls.

As for best practices, see https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services, where the ServiceStack philosophy is discussed.  In particular the recommendation to use:

> Code-first POCO's
>
> Since it promotes clean, re-usable code, ServiceStack has always encouraged the use of code-first POCO's for just about everything. i.e. the same POCO can be used:
>
> - In Request and Response DTO's (on client and server)
> - In JSON, JSV and CSV Text Serializers
> - As the data model in OrmLite, db4o and NHibernate
> - As the entities stored in Redis
> - As blobs stored in Caches and Sessions
> - Dropped and executed in MQ's services
> - Dehydrating complex configurations into
>
> Leveraging different technologies whose functionality is built around POCO's offer un-precedented levels of re-use, reduces friction, promotes consistent, more usable and easier to rationale code-bases.

Comment: thanks for the answer marfarma.
your example is more or like the same as the approach i've chosen. i also added object inclusion in a recursive way.
i hope this is not a loophole that will be fixed by servicestack one day

Comment: Here's another take on the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18993146/149060 for your consideration.